# PowerBI doesn't Refresh

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have several PowerBI reports that don't refresh automatically or whenever I press refresh in the website and I have to use PowerBI desktop app to refresh it manually and then save it or publish it again.

The reports use direct queries in MySQL db and are shown in PowerBI website. BTW, These are the PowerBI reports not dashboards. Also I tried to use Automatic Refresh but it failed every time.

Comment: What "refresh" do you press in the web site? Do you understand that some data sources require the data gateway to refresh data sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a screenshot of Power BI in the web:

[image]

When you click the Refresh command, it just expires the cache and reloads it from the data source. So if you have had a scheduled refresh or uploaded a new data set this will enable you to see the updated data.

It will NOT refresh the underlying data source. Data refresh is not done with this button.

If you use online content packs, the data refresh of the underlying data source is determined in the individual content pack.

If you use a PBX with your own data sources, you will need to use the data gateway to schedule data refreshes (or run them manually). Then you don't need to refresh the PIBX in PowerBI desktop and re-publish the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well Microsoft Power BI Provides a way to refresh the data automatically by configuring the schedule Refresh in the Power BI Service. So, that wherever there is updated data in the queue it will automatically refresh the data based on schedule time. Below are steps for configuring the schedule refresh.

1. Open Power BI workspace.
2. Switch to report tab as shown in the image here.

[image: Click here to see the image]

3. Once you click on the button then you can see the new three icons as in the image here.
   [image: Click here to see the image]
4. First and second are for report creation and refresh data. But the third icon is for schedule refresh.
   [image: Click here to see the image]

Once you have successfully completed the above steps then your data or report will automatically get refreshed.